# Service Bus topics

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

I have a springboot micrservices application that needs to subscribe to topic and all copies of the container should get the message. I am used to activemq where you can connect directly to the topic and all containers get the message.

I set my appliation.yaml like:

```
   servicebus:
     connection-string: ${AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_URL}
     idle-timeout: 1800000
     pricing-tier: standard
     topic-client-id: ${AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC_CLIENT_ID}
     listener:
       subscription-durable: false
```

I set the listener as:

```
  @JmsListener(destination = "edge-bindermgmt-request-state", containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(RequestProcessingStateChange requestProcessingStateChange){
    log.info("Received: {}", requestProcessingStateChange);
  }
```

With the following I am only getting the message in one copy of the service:

```
  @JmsListener(destination = "edge-bindermgmt-request-state", containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",
          subscription = "edge-bindermgmt-request-state-subscription")
  public void receiveMessage(RequestProcessingStateChange requestProcessingStateChange){
    log.info("Received: {}", requestProcessingStateChange);
  }
```

So what I want is to setup the subscription on the fly, rather than having to set it up in:
[screenshot of subscriptions page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z55Z6.png)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is wondering, you need the premium subscription for Service Bus for that. I ended up going with ActiveMQ instead.